# What does "npm rebuild" actually do?

Tags: npm

I've been struggling with a module that does not build after running `npm rebuild` (namely, [`@getinsomnia/node-libcurl`](https://npmjs.com/package/@getinsomnia/node-libcurl/)), even though it does on `npm install` without `--ignore-scripts`.

I workaround that by running `npx node-pre-gyp install` in the module directory, but I'd like to understand why doesn't this behave as I expect it to do - build the module.

[npm docs for npm rebuild say](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-rebuild):

> This command runs the `npm build` command on the matched folders.

What does `npm build` do though? Documentation for it [only exists for npm v6](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-build) and not any newer releases, I can't run `npm build` on my npm v8 either ("unknown command"), and even that documentation doesn't say anything to me:

> This is the plumbing command called by npm link and npm install.
> It should generally be called during installation, but if you need to run it directly, run:
> `npm build`

Answer (score -3):

**npm build** will fail

**npm run build** will work

- assuming that it is configured properly within *package.json*